# How do you have jquery slide up and down on hover without distorting shape?

Tags: jquery, html

How do you have an object slide up as if it were hidden behind something, rather than bending out.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/7fNbM/15/)

In the jsfiddle demo, you can see the circle bends flat as it slides, but I'd like it to slide out as if it were hidden behind something. (I unfortunately can't just put an image or div with the same background color over the circle and have the circle underneath slide upward.)

html

```
<div class="button">Hover</div>
<div class="box">
    Sliding down!
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('.box').hide();
$('.button').hover(
    function() {
        $('.box').slideToggle('slow');
    }
);
```

**update:**
You guys had really good answers! But I found one of the solutions:
http://jsfiddle.net/7fNbM/36/
I decided to use the animate() effect and just wrap the .button div and .box div in a container, and give the container a specific height, specific width, and overflow of hidden. This way I wouldn't have to cover the image in the background and it provides the effect I was looking for.

**Update, again:**
I just found out you can easily have this effect using a jquery ui effect called blind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it bends is because you are using slideToggle which alters the height of the object to make it slide back up. What you want to do is make an object, say your circle. and instead of animating the height using slideToggle you want to animate the position to hide it off the screen or behind another object.

something to the extend of:

```
$('.button').hover(
        function() {
            $('.box').stop().animate({top:40}, 800);
        }, function(){
            $('.box').stop().animate({top:-180}, 800);
        }
    );
```

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7fNbM/17/

Comment: This is close but what the .box and .button were at the center of the page? you would still be able to see the .box. http://jsfiddle.net/7fNbM/21/

Comment: if it's at the center of the page just add another div for a background to hide it behind.

Comment: ? you can't see the .box div. I wouldn't be able to use this .hider box anyway because I need to put the button on top of an image.

Comment: what browser are you using? I can see the box fine. Mind you haven't tested or fixed this for IE in any way :) Just showing you how this could work.

Comment: oops turned out the result panel was too short so there was scrolling problems, hehe. i solved the problem, but thanks for your help and time! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a wrapper for the box like this

```
<div class="button">Hover</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    Sliding down!
  </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript

```
$('.container').hide();
    $('.button').hover(
        function() {
            $('.container').slideToggle('slow');
        }
    );
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7fNbM/28/ this would be what you're talkinga about right? but the circle isn't actually moving, it's not quite the same effect.

Comment: oops sorry, the link I provided was wrong, i just replaced it. but that was what i was talking about, the .box isn't actually moving.

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/7fNbM/20/

```
   $('.button').mouseenter(
        function() {
            $('.box').stop();
            $('.box').animate({top: 50, left:0}, 400);
    }
    ).mouseleave(
        function() {
            $('.box').stop();
            $('.box').animate({top: -180, left:0}, 400);
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the button on top of an image, what about this one?

Check here, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/MW5Gq/1/

```
$('.button').hover(
    function() {            
        $('.box').stop().animate({'top':'50','opacity':'1'}, 800);
    }, function(){
        $('.box').stop().animate({'top':'-125','opacity':'0'}, 800);           
    }     
);
```

Comment: not quite the effect i was looking for, but thanks for your help! I solved the problem :)